# iPhone: Safari doesn't work well with JavaScript turned off

Tags: ios, javascript

Why does my iPhone require JavaScript to be turned on for Safari to work well, while my other iPhone does not require the same?

I have the following two iPhones, both running iOS 11.4.1 (current as of this writing):

1. An iPhone 8 Plus, where Safari doesn't work with JavaScript turned-off.
2. An iPhone 6 Plus, where Safari works well with JavaScript turned-off.

Comment: Is there one specific site you have having where it works well on one phone and not well on the other? What precise thing isn't well?

Comment: The modern internet **cannot** operate properly without JavaScript

Comment: It will help if you can [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/332729/edit) the question to specify the version of iOS running on both the iPhones. Also, is there a specific site which works on 6 and doesn't on 8 Plus?

Comment: Both iphones (6+ and 8+) are using ios version 11.4.1. Tried accessing a website (eg. putlocker) on my 6+ with the javascript off and the page is loaded. However when accessing the same website on my 8+ with its javascript off; the page just won’t load - it was unresponsive.

Comment: I have my javascript switched on on my iphone8+ now and everything is working fine. Just would like to understand why my other iphone does not require javascript to be turned on but works the same? Much thanks!

Comment: @user297510 Can you try to reload the site after closing tab in Safari, closing Safari and restarting the iPhone?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well however the website still wouldn’t load. It was when I switched on my Javascript and refreshed the page and then the page was loaded.